# Extract mixed data from xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to do extract content from a node in a xml file that has mixed child nodes. Here is a copy of the layout:

```
<content>
  bla bal bla...
  <p />
  <img url="me3_img1.jpg"></img>blaa bal
   bla laal laal
  <p />
</content>
```

The "p" tag suggest that the following content (image and text) should be placed into a next paragraph. The image will be created with html, where the source of the image is the URL attribute of the self defined img tag in the xml.

Thus the output would be:

```
 <div>
    <p>
      bla bal bla...
    </p>

    <p>
      <img src = "me3_img1.jpg"/>blaa bal
       bla laal laal
    </p>
  </div>
```

It would be helpful to know where to start or have a basic idea on how to do this.
(ps: We are only allowed to use version 1.0 of xpath and xslt)

I have managed to do the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./review/content/*">
  <xsl:if test="self::text()">
    Display text
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="self::p">
    <br/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="self::img">
    Display image
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The self::p test and self::img test works, but the self::text() test doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is not XML, you should close the `<img/>` tag. To fetch all text contents, use `//text()`. It is not possible to load any image contents with plain XPath/XSLT; you will need to respecify what shall happen here. You might need to enable whitespace-preservation to get exactly this result, depending on the processor chosen.

Comment: Do you actually want just text output, or are you still outputting HTML? If you are outputting HTML it would help if you showed the actual HTML tags in your expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the XML looks like this:

```
<content>
    bla bal bla...
    <p />
    <img url="me3_img1.jpg">blaa bal</img>
    bla laal laal
    <p />
</content>
```

Try this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="review/content/node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=". = not(node())">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="./preceding::text()[1]" /></p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test=". = text()">
                <img><xsl:attribute name="src">url('<xsl:value-of select="./@url" />' </xsl:attribute></img>
                <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I am trying to make a html document, and not a pdf. But I used your test=".=text()". And now I am getting some output but only parts of the text.